# NoReverseMatch although get_absolute_url returns the right URL

Tags: django, url

I am trying to use get_absolute_url with kwargs in my Post model.

in my model I got slug field and the following code for `get_absolute_url`

```
class Post(models.Model):
......
......


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.id, 'slug':self.slug})
```

in `urls.py`

```
url(r'^p/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w.@+-]+)/$',PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail')
```

in my template I got :

```
     <ul>
    {% for post in object_list %}
    <li>
      <a href="{% url post.get_absolute_url %}">
        <b>{{ post.title}}</b> 
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

when I use : `python manage.py shell`

```
from website.models import Post
p = Post.objects.first()
p.get_absolute_url()
# returns this
u'/p/1/this-is-a-test/'
```

it returns the right URL which is /p/1/this-is-test/
but when I use it in the **template** like `post.get_absolute_url` it returns NoReverseMatch.

I checked lots of questions here and copied the answers but it did not work.

what I am doing wrong please ?

Comment: Please post the relevant code - your `urls.py` and the actual template code that fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `url` template tag. Just do this:

```
<a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"></a>
```

Your current code is resulting in `reverse` being called twice, one inside `get_absolute_url` and once with the output of `get_absolute_url`. That is why it fails.

Comment: got this error now `Invalid block tag: 'post.get_absolute_url', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'`

Comment: did you change `{%` to `{{` ?

Comment: Are you sure you're doing `{{ post.get_absolute_url }}` and not `{% post.get_absolute_url %}`?